# regex to match multiple subnets delimited by a space

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

current regex to match multiple subnets delimited by a `space` `rexp = /^([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]){3}(?:\/[0-2]\d|\/3[0-2])?$(\s(^([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]){3}(?:\/[0-2]\d|\/3[0-2])?$))*$/)`

test string `192.168.2.1/24 192.168.2.1/32`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex seems to be broken. You can try this one:

```
^([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]){3}(?:\/[0-2]\d|\/3[0-2])?(\s+([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]){3}(?:\/[0-2]\d|\/3[0-2]))*$
```

Another option is to parse the string using Javascript and use a simpler regex for each piece. Here is an example:

```
const s = '192.168.2.1/24 192.168.2.1/32 250.161.23.1/32 0.1.2.1/01';
const pattern = /([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]){3}(?:\/[0-2]\d|\/3[0-2])/;
const result = s.trim().split(/\s+/).map(e => e.match(pattern) != null).reduce((result, next) => result && next, true);
console.log(result);
```

This prints:

```
true
```

Comment: first regex you suggested does not work on regex101
https://regex101.com/r/mZwJcd/1

Comment: @VaibhavChauhan It does work, your link adds an extra character after the regex.  If you remove that extra char, then you will see it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can certainly decompose the string using regex, it might be much easier using code like this:

```
subnetsString = "192.168.2.1/24 192.168.2.1/32";
subnets = subnetsString.split(" ");
firstSubnet = subnets[0];
ip = firstSubnet.split("/")[0];

console.log(ip);  // output: 192.168.2.1
```